# Adding style to a published layer using GeoServer REST API with Node.js

Tags: geoserver, rest, geoserver-rest-api, node-js

Lets say I have a custom style in GeoServer and after I created a new layer, I want to add the style to that layer. I am using [this](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/layers.html) link for documentation.

```
function editLayerStyle(layerName, body) {
url = `http://admin:geoserver@IP:PORT/geoserver/rest/layers/{layerName}/styles`

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.post(url, {
        body,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml' }
    }, function (error, { statusCode }, body) {
        if (error) {
            return reject({ success: false, statusCode: statusCode, message: body })
        }
        if (statusCode === 201) {
            return resolve({ success: true, message: 'Style added to layer' })
        } else {
            return reject({ success: false, statusCode: statusCode, message: 'Unknown Error' })
        }
    })
})
}

let layerName = 'layer_name'
let body = `
<styles>
    <style>
        <name>{style_name}</name>    /// name of my style
        <filename>{style_name.sld}</filename>  /// format of style
    </style>
<styles>`

try {
    await editLayerStyle(layerName, body)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

I get the error even I tried to change the style and the content type.

Comment: You don't link to the SLD file, it should be the XML file that goes with it

Comment: But my style is already there. I am not adding a new style, I am adding an existing style.

Comment: that is why you add the link to the xml file not a new SLD file.

Comment: Thanks, How I give the link of a existing style to body of request?